# How to write a vector into several columns of the same row of a data table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have an empty data table and want to write a pre-defined vector of numeric data into a subset of columns of the data table (all in the same row). Here an example:

```
require(data.table)
mydf <- data.table(matrix(0, nrow = 13, ncol = 15))
input <- seq(2.22, 14.22, by = 1)
set(mydf, 3L, 2L:14L, input)
# Trying another form of writing into the data table 
mydf[3, 2:14] <- input
```

This returns the error: 
`Error in set(mydf, 3L, 2L:14L, input) : Supplied 13 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'V2'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.`

I cannot manually write in every element as in my actual problem this command is in an `apply` function where the input vector size differs and the number of columns to write the vector in differs in the same manner. How can I write the vector in columns 2 to 14 of row 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as.list`

```
library(data.table)
mydf[3, 2:14 := as.list(input)]
mydf

#   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9   V10   V11   V12   V13   V14 V15
#1:  0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00   0
#2:  0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00   0
#3:  0 2.22 3.22 4.22 5.22 6.22 7.22 8.22 9.22 10.22 11.22 12.22 13.22 14.22   0
#4:  0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00   0
#5:  0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00   0
#....
```

This will also work with `set`

```
set(mydf, 3L, 2L:14L, as.list(input))
```